# Trying to Inject a JavaScript into webpage using mockttp

Tags: javascript, fiddler, mockttp

So far i have tried the below code but its throwing me an error
`Failed to handle request: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')`

```
var INJECT = "<script src='https://examlple.com/googletranslate.js'></script>"

await server.forAnyRequest().thenPassThrough({
    beforeResponse: (res) => {
        var newBody = res.body.text.replace("<head>", "<head>"+INJECT)
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: newBody
        };
    }
});
```

How can i solve this error and inject a JavaScript into the page successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockttp aside, from this error by itself you can tell that somewhere you're trying to read `X.replace` for an `X` that's undefined.

In this case, there's a clear probable cause: `res.body.text.replace(...)`. This tells you that `res.body.text` is undefined, so something is wrong there.

In fact, if you look at Mockttp's reference docs for the [CompletedBody](https://httptoolkit.github.io/mockttp/interfaces/CompletedBody.html) type, you'll see that there is no `.text` property - it's `.getText()` instead, and this returns a promise, not a fixed value (this is one of the breaking changes from [Mockttp v3](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp/releases/tag/v3.0.0)). These are asynchronous because reading the text of a request may require non-trivial decoding steps, e.g. to decode Brotli data.

That means you need to make your callback `async`, use `await`, and call `getText()`. I haven't tested, but I think this version of your example should work correctly:

```js
var INJECT = "<script src='https://examlple.com/googletranslate.js'></script>"

await server.forAnyRequest().thenPassThrough({
    beforeResponse: async (res) => { // <-- Make the callback async
        var oldBody = await res.body.getText() // <-- await the result of getText()
        var newBody = oldBody.replace("<head>", "<head>"+INJECT)
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: newBody
        };
    }
});
```